# Calculating Bias in R

Tags: r, bias

Write a simulation experiment to estimate the bias of the estimator λˆ= 1/ X¯ by sampling using x=rexp(n,rate=5) and recording the values of 1/mean(x). You should find that the bias is λ/n−1. Here we’ve used λ = 5 but the result will hold for any λ. Here is my solution ( I dont get λ/n−1). Am I doing something wrong here?

```
set.seed(1)
lambda <- 5
x <- rexp(n= 1e5, rate = lambda )
samp.mean <- mean(x)
lam.est <- 1/samp.mean
lam.est ##4.986549

bias <- abs(lambda - lam.est)
bias ##0.01345146
```

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us what you understand thus far, what 
you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to 
help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing.

Comment: +1. There is a fascinating and deep statistical question lurking here: although the bias indeed is $\lambda/(n-1),$ as $n$ grows large it becomes increasingly likely that the bias *as estimated in the dataset* will differ appreciably from its expectation by an amount that grows more slowly than $1/n.$ Consequently, *computer simulation can be misleading.* I recommend studying a *running estimate* of the bias, suitably scaled, as in `lambda <- 5;
x <- rexp(1e4, rate=lambda);
m <- seq_along(x) / cumsum(x) - lambda;
plot(m * (seq_along(x)-1), type="l");
abline(h=lambda)`

Answer (score 3):

Your issue stems from the fact that you only ran one simulation. Recall that the formal definition of the bias of an estimator is :

$$ Bias(\hat{\theta}) = E(\hat{\theta})-\theta $$

In a simulation you approximate the expected value of your estimator by its sample mean.

Here is some R code to get what you want :

```
> set.seed(1)
> lambda <- 5
> n <- 50
> X <- matrix(rexp(n*1e5, rate = lambda),n)
> samp.mean <- apply(X,2,mean)
> lam.est <- 1/samp.mean
> 
> bias <- abs(lambda - mean(lam.est))
> bias
[1] 0.1001163
> # Approximately equal to lambda/(n-1) and will be if n -> infty
```

Comment: I am not sure whether you meant to give a complete answer or just a hint, but comparing just the difference between the mean of estimates from several tests and $\lambda$ is one step towards a final answer but not enough.

Comment: Indeed this is not a full answer and I only provide the author an estimate of what the bias of the MLE of an exponential is. I provided some code to show the author what is the correct way to estimate this bias as he or she seems to be a new contributor.

Comment: The correct way indeed includes a look at multiple estimates (and the coding is, I believe, something that the author should have tried figuring out themselves). But the correct way would be to also estimate the variance of the estimate. Just the difference is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

You computed the outcome of only a single test.

Could you instead write a program that repeats this test a lot of times. Then look at how the distribution of the estimates is. Is the distribution of the estimates centered around $\lambda$ or is there a bias?